# How I should build the official Linux driver for Wireless PCI card D-Link DWA-525 v.A2 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, compiling, pci

I have a new PCI wifi card, D-Link DW-525. By now i'm having no problem, since it has running a free driver.  Using the command ***sudo lspci -v***   it returns this:

> 01:05.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5360 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R
>
> Subsystem: D-Link System Inc DWA-525 Wireless N 150 Desktop Adapter (rev.A2)
>
> Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 20
>
> Memory at fea00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
>
> Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
>
> **Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci**

But I was wondering if i could run an official driver. So i downloaded the one for this card in d-link website [this is the link](ftp://ftp.dlink.eu/Products/dwa/dwa-525/driver_software/DWA-525_drv_revA2_v2_6_1_Linux_all_en_20130418.zip)

I found i had to compile the thing; the readme told me following instructions:

> 1> $tar -xvzf DPB_RT2860_Linux_STA_x.x.x.x.tgz
>      go to "./DPB_RT2860_Linux_STA_x.x.x.x" directory.
>
> **2> In Makefile**
>
> set the "MODE = STA" in Makefile and chose the TARGET to Linux by set "TARGET = LINUX"
>   define the linux kernel source include file path LINUX_SRC
>   modify to meet your need.
>
> 3> In os/linux/config.mk
>
> define the GCC and LD of the target machine
>
> define the compiler flags CFLAGS modify to meet your need.
>
> ** Build for being controlled by NetworkManager or wpa_supplicant wext functions
>        Please set 'HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y' and 'HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y'.
>     => #>cd wpa_supplicant-x.x
>        => #>./wpa_supplicant -Dwext -ira0 -c wpa_supplicant.conf -d
>     ** Build for being controlled by WpaSupplicant with Ralink Driver
>     Please set 'HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y' and 'HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=n'.
>        => #>cd wpa_supplicant-0.5.7
>     => #>./wpa_supplicant -Dralink -ira0 -c wpa_supplicant.conf -d
>
> 4> $make
>     # compile driver source code
>     # To fix "error: too few arguments to function ¡¥iwe_stream_add_event"
>       => $patch -i os/linux/sta_ioctl.c.patch os/linux/sta_ioctl.c
>
> 5> $cp RT2860STA.dat  /etc/Wireless/RT2860STA/RT2860STA.dat
>
> 6> load driver
>      #[kernel 2.4]
>      #    $/sbin/insmod rt2860sta.o
>      #    $/sbin/ifconfig ra0 inet YOUR_IP up
>
> #[kernel 2.6]
>      #    $/sbin/insmod rt2860sta.ko
>      #    $/sbin/ifconfig ra0 inet YOUR_IP up
>
> 7> unload driver
>      $/sbin/ifconfig ra0 down
>     $/sbin/rmmod rt2860sta

And i mostly lost since step 2 :P

So then, is all this neccesary, to makefile and stuff, or i should keep the free driver as it is?

Oh btw my kernel is 3.15.10 :P

Other option is to use **ndiswrapper** but i'm not sure, since my knowledge about this things is not too deep and i could mess up all for nothing. Hope you can help me guys and girls :D

Comment: Why? Do you know what's the difference between the "free" and the "official" drivers? What if I was to tell you they are the same?

Comment: You have a driver in place: rt2800pci. What is wrong that prompts you to try an older, presumably less good version of the same thing?

Comment: mikewhatever - mm I'm mostly a regular user, so maybe i missed the difference between "free" and "official". When you install a package from your hardware provider's website i call that official, like AMD drivers. Anyway, I just wanted to be sure my pci card wasn't going to suffer some error because I didn't checked everything was going fine.

Comment: chili555 I know that's the driver, i'm not trying to test something older... i went to website of D-Link to get the most recent driver. What i'm missing?

Comment: D-Link gets the driver from Realtek, the chip manufacturer, as does Ubuntu and the entirety of Linux. The file downloaded from D-Link is in no way "official." If you can connect, upload, download, etc., there is no reason I can see to try a different one-size-maybe-fits-all driver.

Comment: Thats what i wanted to know, just wanted to be sure it was everything ok. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This answer compiled from comments made by chili555 and other users

The 'free' driver for your wifi card is `rt2800pci` that is in use by the system now.  The driver you see from D-Link's site is actually from the chip manufacturer, Realtek, and is in no way 'official' on D-Link's site.

Further, the entirety of Linux, including Ubuntu, gets the drivers from Realtek as well.  So long as everything works, there is no need to try a different one-size-maybe-fits-all driver.